# C# Office2010 like backstage

Tags: c#, uiview

I am looking for a good and free (and possibly open-source) BackStage element, based on the Office 2010 backstage. I've already found Elegant UI, but the free demo version of it does a lot of crap to my app - like replacing the icon, creating an annoying popup, etc.

Here is what I would like to achieve:
http://www.prof-uis.com/elegant-ribbon/feature-tour/dotnet_backstage_view.aspx

Only the stage view, I don't need the ribbon.

If someone knows a good solution, please share it!

Answer (score 0):

I've found a partial solution, called Fluent. It is an open-source UI kit, for WPF (what I don't want to use).

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you don't want to use WPF? WinForms is not under active development anymore and it seems like WPF will get the standard UI technology for rich clients in the .NET world (and don't forget Windows Phone 7 and Silverlight).

Comment: I am planning to release the application for Linux too (using Mono) and AFAIK while WinForms is almost totally ported to Linux, WPF isn't. And do not forget about a special library I am using, what is written for WinForms!